# Form is submitted anyway in Firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, jsonp, onsubmit

```
var form0 = document.forms[0];

form0.onsubmit = function(e){
    alert("form submitted");
    var email = form0.elements["email"].value; 
    var url = "https://bpi.briteverify.com/emails.json?address="+email+"&apikey=my-key&callback=emailResult";

    jsonp(url, function(data) {
       if (data.status != "valid") {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("INVALID EMAIL");
       }
    }); 
}

function jsonp(url, callback) {
    var callbackName = 'jsonp_callback_' + Math.round(100000 * Math.random());
    window[callbackName] = function(data) {
        delete window[callbackName];
        document.body.removeChild(script);
        callback(data);
    };

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url + (url.indexOf('?') >= 0 ? '&' : '?') + 'callback=' + callbackName;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

This works in Chrome and Safari, but not Firefox. Although the 'Form Submitted" alert is shown, but nothing after that.

Is this a Firefox issue or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why you're calling `e.preventDefault()` in the callback of `jsonp()`? This belongs in the `submit` handler.

Comment: @Andreas because in `jsonp()` I know whether the email is valid or not. Thats when I decide whether to continue form processing or not.

Comment: But the form is already submitted at this point of time. Move the `e.preventDefault()` in the `submit` handler and submit the form in the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
form0.onsubmit = function(e){
    alert("form submitted");
    var email = form0.elements["email"].value; 
    var url = "https://bpi.briteverify.com/emails.json?address="+email+"&apikey=my-key&callback=emailResult";

    jsonp(url, function(data) {
        if (data.status != "valid") {
            alert("INVALID EMAIL");
        }
        else
        {
            form0.onsubmit = null;
            form0.submit();
        }
    }); 

    return false;
}
```